# Full width separator for rows of table inside of a cell

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to figure out how to make a separator between the rows of a table inside of a cell.

This is my try, but as you can see the separator between "hola" and "ola" is not full width:

```css
table.second {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.second td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}
table.second tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 0;
}
table.second tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
table.second tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
table.second tr td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse">
<tr>
<td style="border-right: 1px solid black">
hello
</td>
<td>
<table class="second">
<tr>
  <td>
    hola
  </td>
</tr>
<tr >
  <td>
    ola
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have used the possibility #1 of this [article](https://css-tricks.com/table-borders-inside/) for the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to achieve "hello" text to span two rows, I will suggest you use "rowspan" instead of nested tables;

The CSS styles are unnecessary since the borders are applied inline within HTML already.

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse">
   <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
      <td rowspan="2" style="border-right: 1px solid black">
         hello
      </td>
      <td>
         hola
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         ola
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```